# Apache Commons Math Normal Cumulative Probability

Tags: java, apache-commons, normal-distribution, apache-commons-math

Wikipedia [has listed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Numerical_approximations_for_the_normal_CDF) a variety of numerical methods for computing cumulative probability of a normal distribution. However, with Apache Commons Math you do not need know about any of them as the library simply does the job for you:

```
NormalDistribution normal = new NormalDistribution(mu, sigma);
normal.cumulativeProbability(x);
```

For some research project, I'm interested to know what method they use. Does anyone know what method Apache Commons Math uses to approximate the normal cumulative value? Is it from the methods listed in wikipedia or they have implemented something different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The beauty of open source software is that you can always [check the source code](https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-math.git;a=blob;f=src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math4/distribution/NormalDistribution.java;h=6313ef04d3874c70fbd38c77783a8d6c86cf7824;hb=HEAD#l191). The implementation of `cumulativeProbability` is rather simple, it just returns

```
0.5 * (1 + Erf.erf(dev / (standardDeviation * SQRT2)));
```

where `Erf.erf` computes the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). It's defined [here](https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-math.git;a=blob;f=src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math4/special/Erf.java;h=98722301731295f3eb437b6b3b3e603b2af70578;hb=HEAD#l65).

And no, it doesn' use any of the special methods in the mentioned Wikipedia article. It's just a straight-forward implementation of the formula

[image]

Comment: Thanks. For the sake of completeness, I'd like to mention that the error function does not have a closed formula and is approximated using some numerical method.

Comment: Right, you can see exactly what Commons Math does by looking at the implementation of `Erf` in the `special` package.  It does use methods referenced in the Wikipedia Erf article[1]. [1]:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Approximation_with_elementary_functions

Answer (score 1):

You can probably see the source code or the javadoc. See there http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/source-repository.html

and

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/NormalDistribution.html

Also, there is alot of information in the user's guide. The section about distribution seems interesting: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/distribution.html

Comment: Thanks but my question is not answered in the javadoc. And I tend to ask my peers before investigating the source code.

Comment: @Pro.Hessam That's kinda rude. You can just look at the source code in a matter of seconds, while you choose not to do that but rely on the time and patience of others to do your work.

Comment: @Carsten I was hoping to find someone familiar with the library in the community to answer my question. Not to waste anybody's time.